# How to add all default application proxies to custom application proxy group

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, custom, service-application

I have created a web application using powershell and associate it with custom application proxy group. But i also want to add all default application proxies except Managed Metadata Service to my custom proxy group using powershell. How i do this using powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following commands to add the new member in the custom proxy group.

```
#obtain the identity of the service application
$SAProxy = Get‐SPServiceApplicationProxy | ? {$_.DisplayName ‐eq "Name of Service Application"}

#add the Service Application's proxy to the proxy group you want to

Add‐SPServiceApplicationProxyGroupMember "name of proxy group" ‐Member $SAProxy
```

you have to add all the Services App one by one or if you can loop them.

http://jantjesworld.blogspot.com/2013/09/proxy-groups-in-sharepoint-2013.html